# Custom Module disappear when cache is on

Tags: magento2, module, extensions, cache, menu

Help please,  I'm really stuck!

I have a custom module (ObserverInterface) to construct all my menu. When de Cache is on, you can see this module only in few pages.

Comment: Please post your code or errors from `var\log`

Comment: Have you cleared all your cache and built your statics?

Comment: I clear everything, also I setup:di:compile... I don't know what to do!!

Comment: try cacheable=false on your custom block XML file

Comment: Ankit Shah, I don't have any record in the logs. :-(

Comment: Keyur Shah, Where?? I have in my module 3 xml layouts: events.xml, di.xml and module.xml. But I don't have any block inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jajajaja, it was easy!!! Instead of the menu, we had a "esi:include" tag. This tag supposed to be rendered by the Varnish Cache.

The thing is that we don't have the Varnish cache instaled, but the configuration for Caching Application in Store > Settings > Configuration > Advanced > System, in the Full Page Cache section, was "Varnish Caching".

Easy to fix, change **Varnish Caching** for **Built-in Application** (of course if you don't have the varnish installed).

Thanks to every one!!